# type error in jQuery 1.8 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery

This snippet of code;

```
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
        $('div.tabs ul.tabSelect a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide();
        tabContainers.filter(this.hash).fadeIn('slow');
        $('div.tabs ul.tabSelect a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Works fine in jQuery 1.5 but throws a "type error $ is not a function" error with jQuery 1.10 (or 1.8)

What am i missing here? It's not the first time it's cropped up with migrating god to later jQuery version.

```
window.jQuery(function () {
        var tabContainers = window.jQuery('div.tabs > div');
        tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

        window.jQuery('div.tabs ul.tabSelect a').click(function () {
            tabContainers.hide();
            tabContainers.filter(this.hash).fadeIn('slow');
            window.jQuery('div.tabs ul.tabSelect a').removeClass('selected');
            window.jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
            return false;
        }).filter(':first').click();
    });
```

this works just fine. There are no other libraries, just two calls
one
    `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>`

is to 1.10.1 and throws the error

```
`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>`
```

doesn't.

that's my question. if you don't understand it don't answer it and don't give me minus reputation because you can't be bothered to read my post.

Comment: Please check whether you loaded jQuery file in the page by using Firebug/Chrome/Fiddler tool

Comment: And you didn't load both versions

Comment: `$ is not a function` means jQuery isn't loaded properly *OR* you have another library on your page that also uses `$`.  You might need to use `$.noConflict()`.  What other libraries are on your page?  Are you only loading one version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation. A complete and utter solution of the problem.

**Aliasing the jQuery Namespace**

When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call $.noConflict() to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is called, the $ shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write jQuery each time we would normally write $. However, the handler passed to the .ready() method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our .ready() handler without affecting other code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This error does not comes from the upgrade of jQuery, since `$` is still available in current versions.

Check you don't forget to include jQuery, that the file path is OK (use your browser's javascript console, accessible by F12 key) and that you didn't include jQuery two times (older and newer versions together).

Another problem could be that there is a `jQuery.noConflict();` call somewhere in your code. This function is meant to prevent those conflict between different versions. You can, for example, do `$my_jquery = jQuery.noConflict();` and then use it this way `$my_jquery('my_selector')...`

Comment: See the answer below for a complete solution - marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You've incorrectly loaded the library:

- Check if the lib is loaded before the script is called
- Check if you've actually loaded jQuery and not a partially downloaded file, bad file name, or other errors on your console exist.

And/or you're loading a second library which replaces the $ global, ie, Prototype. Or, you've re-assigned the $ global.

Or you're just using cut+paste code from a website and you've copied in a similar looking character that is not actually `$` and the computer won't treat it as such.

That's the only way you can have this issue.

Comment: substituting window.jQuery for $ works just fine. I know the library is loaded, there is only one library loaded.

Comment: `window.jQuery(function () {
   var tabContainers = window.jQuery('div.tabs > div');
   tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
   
   window.jQuery('div.tabs ul.tabSelect a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide();
    tabContainers.filter(this.hash).fadeIn('slow');
    window.jQuery('div.tabs ul.tabSelect a').removeClass('selected');
    window.jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
   }).filter(':first').click();
  });
`

Comment: Put code in your question, not here. If your $ doesn't work and window.jQuery does, it means you've over-written the $ global. Re-read my answer, I've already covered that.

Comment: I have answered you. I haven't. All I did was change one line of code, the call to jQuery from 1.5 to 1.10. NOTHING ELSE. I don't appreciate this reputation downrating because YOU don't understand the problem.

Comment: Yeah stay classy. I'm not the one down voting you. You don't even have reputation to lose, you can't go lower than 1. Thanks for the attitude.